# JQuery ASP.NET .change event not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onchange

I know this question has been asked quite a bit, but nothing seems to work for me. I've read many questions and answers.

I'm using a JQuery event to handle the event of an ASP.NET control, but the event will not fire.

This is what I've tried:

My DropDownList:

`<asp:DropDownList ID="List_ValueStream" runat="server" Width="195px" />`

My attempts to add events to the DropDownList, all tested separately:

in:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
          ...
    </script>
```

/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=List_ValueStream.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            alert('1 Handler for .change() called.');
        });
    });
```

/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#List_ValueStream").change(function () {
            alert('2 Handler for .change() called.');
        });
    });
```

/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#List_ValueStream").on('change', function () {
            alert('3 Handler for .change() called.');
        });
    });
```

/

```
    $("#<%=List_ValueStream.ClientID%>").change(function () {
          alert('4 Handler for .change() called.');
    });
```

/

```
    $("#List_ValueStream").change(function () {
        alert('5 Handler for .change() called.');
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the runat="server"?  Are you getting any errors in the chrome/ff/IE developer consoles?

Comment: When you view the HTML source of the page in your browser, is the `id` actually `List_ValueStream`?  Do you watch the console to check for JavaScript errors?

Comment: Does it work with a simple `<select id="List_ValueStream">`

Comment: As @mellamokb said, the ID by the server control doesnt necessarily have to be what you see on the .aspx. Its more safe to use the `CssClass` attribute.

Comment: That's why he's tried using `ClientID`

Comment: Is the `$(document).ready()` code inside the `<script></script>` tags used to load jQuery or inside a separate `<script>` tag after that one? If it's the former, move it to its own `<script>` tag.

Comment: It's all in the same `<script></script>`. Thanks, everyone for the other suggestions. I'm trying them out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you written script between these two lines. Then write your script in a sperate script tag as follows

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=List_ValueStream.ClientID%>").change(function () {
        alert('1 Handler for .change() called.');
    });
});
</script>
```

I think only this can be the reason. other wise it is ok.
You can take the advantage of [ClientIDMode=static](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature) if you are using asp.net 4.0 or above. it will not change the id of you control as follow

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEcho2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

So you can get rid of ClientId

Answer (score 4):

you can use like this and work well

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="List_ValueStream" runat="server" Width="195px" onchange="youfunction();"/>
```

Comment: It works, although it's not quite what I need. Thanks though.